# getting error while trying to add time in date using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting data from db with time like 2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z in this I want minutes and add 5 minutes to it I tried using getMinutes() method but it throws an error getMinutes() is not a function.

```
console.log('data as ', obj);
 var dt = obj.starttime; 
console.log('time from database' , dt);
console.log('getMinutes():'  ,dt.setMinutes( dt.getMinutes() + 05 ));

 data as  { id: 4009,
 mid: 1,cid: 41,wid: 7138,oid: null,status: null,options: null,
 starttime: '2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z',duration: null,ordertotal: 50,
  counter: null,closetime: null }

 time from database 2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z

 Uncaught Error
  message: 'dt.getMinutes is not a function',
```

Comment: What is the `dt`?

Comment: @hsz sorry dt is a variable I edited now

Answer (score 0):

convert the string to Date

```js
 var dt = new Date('2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z');
console.log(dt.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

dt is just a string you need to convert it into date object

```js
let dt = '2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z';

date = new Date(dt);
console.log(date.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to a `Date` by passing it to the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.

Then use `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 5);` to add 5 minutes:

```js
const date = new Date('2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z');
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 5);

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be that, you might be getting the time "2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z" from db as a string. convert it to date format and getMinutes from it.

```
  let dt = "2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z"
  let myTime = new Date(dt);
  console.log(myTime.getMinutes());
```

The above code should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `dt.getMinutes()` maybe not be working because dt is no Timeobject.

Try the following:

```
dt = '2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z'
let dt = new Date (dt);

console.log('getMinutes():'  ,dt.setMinutes( dt.getMinutes() + 05 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have initialized "dt".
Try this :

```
let dt_new = new Date(dt);
let min = dt_new.getMinutes();
```

You need to init dt as date object